# MPI - Disparity between data sent and recieved

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, communication, libpng

I am writing an application using MPI in which the master node has to send parts of an image (read using libpng) to the slave nodes. I have written the following code to distribute the
rows:

```
int num_rows_per_process = ceil(((float)height)/size);

if(rank == 0)
{
    //Send the chunks to the other nodes
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        int y;
        for(y=0;y<num_rows_per_process;y++)
        {
            int row_index = i*num_rows_per_process+y;
            if(row_index >= height)
                break;
            MPI_Send(row_pointers[row_index], width, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, i, row_index, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //Figure out how many rows will I get
    row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * num_rows_per_process); //For the other processes, these are sub rows
    for(int y=0;y<num_rows_per_process;y++)
        {
            int row_index = rank*num_rows_per_process+y;
            if(row_index >= height)
            {
                row_pointers[row_index] = NULL;
                continue;
            }
            row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*) malloc(row_bytes);
            MPI_Recv(row_pointers[y], width, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, row_index, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
}


MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The size/width of the row is 9500 and height is 6280 for the particular image I am using. Also, the datatype `png_byte` is just a typedef for `unsigned char`. When I compare the data received by the slave nodes, only **one row** among the total 9500 rows changes and even in that particular row, only 16 bytes change to 0 (these bytes are not the boundary bytes either). I don't understand how this can happen. Can someone help me?

Comment: Just a suggestion, this is quite easily achieved using MPI_Bcast

Comment: Are you sure that num_rows_per_process is equal for all processes? what if the image size is not divisible by n, the number of processes?